# Can't show Spinner DropDown list inside AlertDialog - Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I have two spinners in an AlertDialog, the spinners look good, and the list of items is correct, it shows the first items of each list. But when I click any of the two spinner, the dropdown list is not displayed to select some other item. The spinners do nothing. This does not happen when I was the same two spinners outside the AlertDialog.

This is the code of AlertDialog:

```
private void mostrar_alertdialog_spinners() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        TextView title = new TextView(this);
        title.setText("Selecciona un archivo:");
        title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 153, 204));
        title.setTextSize(23);
        builder.setCustomTitle(title);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout_spinners = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_spinners,null);
        sp_titulos_carpetas = (Spinner) layout_spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner_titulo_carpetas);
        sp_titulos_textos = (Spinner) layout_spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner_textos_carpetas);

        builder.setView(layout_spinners);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();

        //configuracion de textos en memoria sd
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Textos/";
        File f = new File(path);
        String[] fileStr = f.list();
        ArrayList<String> lista_lista_CARPETAS = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String lista_texto : fileStr) {
            lista_lista_CARPETAS.add(lista_texto);
        }
        Collections.sort(lista_lista_CARPETAS, new AlphanumComparator());

        String[] lista_k = f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                File f = new File(dir, name);
                return f.isDirectory();
            }
        });
        FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isDirectory();
            }
        };
        File[] files = f.listFiles(fileFilter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> carpetas = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista_k);
        carpetas.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        sp_titulos_carpetas.setAdapter(carpetas);

        //ARRAY CON TITULOS DE ARCHIVOS TXT
        String camino = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Textos/" + "Naxos"+ "/";
        File t = new File(camino);
        String[] lista_textos = t.list();
        ArrayList<String> lista_lista_textos = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String lista_texto : lista_textos) {
            if (lista_texto.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
                lista_lista_textos.add(lista_texto);
            }
        }
        for (int index =0; index < lista_lista_textos.size(); index++){
            lista_lista_textos.set(index, WordUtils.capitalizeFully(lista_textos[index].toLowerCase().replace(".txt", "")));
        }
        Collections.sort(lista_lista_textos, new AlphanumComparator());

        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador_textos = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista_lista_textos);
        adaptador_textos.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        sp_titulos_textos.setAdapter(adaptador_textos);
        sp_titulos_textos.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String nombre_texto = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                File sdcard = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Textos/" + "Naxos/");

                //Get the text file
                File file = new File(sdcard, nombre_texto);

                //Read text from file
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "Cp1252"),BUFFER_SIZE);
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(line);
                        text.append('\n');
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
                }
                String nuevoTexto = text.toString().replaceAll("\t", " ");
                String nuevoTextoA = nuevoTexto.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                Holmes1 = nuevoTextoA;
                delimitadores = " ";
                tokenHolmes1 = new StringTokenizer(Holmes1, " ");
                arrayHolmes1 = Holmes1.split(delimitadores);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And the xml for the spinners:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    style="@style/spinner_rojo">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_titulo_carpetas"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        style="@style/spinner_rojo"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"></Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_textos_carpetas"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        style="@style/spinner_rojo"

        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"></Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

And an image:

[image]

Anyone know any possible sulucion to show the drop down list?

Comment: As I understand, you problem is spinner cannot show it's dropdown selection to choose another option, right ? I just copied your code, it worked well for me. What's wrong with you ?

Answer (score 2):

I just copied your code and edit ArrayList. It totally worked for me.

[image]

```
private void mostrar_alertdialog_spinners() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText("Selecciona un archivo:");
    title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 153, 204));
    title.setTextSize(23);
    builder.setCustomTitle(title);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout_spinners = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout,null);
    Spinner sp_titulos_carpetas = (Spinner) layout_spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner_titulo_carpetas);
    Spinner sp_titulos_textos = (Spinner) layout_spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner_textos_carpetas);

    builder.setView(layout_spinners);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();


    ArrayList<String> lista_k = new ArrayList<String>();
    lista_k.add("Path A");
    lista_k.add("Path B");

    ArrayAdapter<String> carpetas = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista_k);
    carpetas.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    sp_titulos_carpetas.setAdapter(carpetas);



    ArrayList<String> lista_lista_textos = new ArrayList<String>();
    lista_lista_textos.add("Path C");
    lista_lista_textos.add("Path D");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador_textos = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista_lista_textos);
    adaptador_textos.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    sp_titulos_textos.setAdapter(adaptador_textos);
    sp_titulos_textos.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this to the end of the code, so you are doing it after setting everything up:

```
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom alert dialog for same. Try this

```
Dialog new_dialog = new Dialog(getParent());                                                            
// new_dialog.setTitle("Book your appointment");
new_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
new_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customize_dialog_list_view);
new_dialog.setCancelable(false);
cuc = new CommanUtilityClass();
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("provider",0);
String services = sp.getString("services",  "");
TextView service = (TextView) new_dialog
        .findViewById(R.id.cdlv_service_provider);
TextView hour = (TextView) new_dialog.findViewById(R.id.cdlv_working_hours);
TextView appointment_time = (TextView) new_dialog.findViewById(R.id.cdlv_appoint_time);
TextView appointment_date = (TextView) new_dialog.findViewById(R.id.cdlv_appoint_date);
//String[] ampm = myTiming[which].split(":");
/*String[] range = myTiming[which].split(":");
int startTimeInt = Integer.parseInt(range[0])
        * 60 + Integer.parseInt(range[1]);
String finalvalue = "";
if(startTimeInt >= 720){
     if(startTimeInt >= 780){

     }else{

     }
}else{
    finalvalue = String.valueOf(range[0] + ":" + range[1] + " AM");
}

for (int i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    String startTimeString = range[i].split("-")[0];
    String endTimeString = range[i].split("-")[1];
    Log.d("Minutes", "startTimeString = " + startTimeString);
    Log.d("Minutes", "endTimeString = " + endTimeString);
    int startTimeInt = Integer.parseInt(startTimeString.split(":")[0])
            * 60 + Integer.parseInt(startTimeString.split(":")[1]);
    int endTimeInt = Integer.parseInt(endTimeString.split(":")[0]) * 60
            + Integer.parseInt(endTimeString.split(":")[1]);


}*/


appointment_time.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Appointment time :</b>" + myTimingToShow[which].split("/")[0]));
appointment_date.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Appointment date :</b>" + selected));

service.setText(Html
        .fromHtml("<b>Service provider :</b>"
                + cuc.toTheUpperCase(bsp_name)));

hour.setText(Html
        .fromHtml("<b>Working hours :</b>"
                + cuc.toTheUpperCase(bsp_availability)));

try {
    lv = (ListView) new_dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.cdlv_list);

    CustomDialogArrayAdapter cdaa = new CustomDialogArrayAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(),
            m_ArrayList);

    lv.setAdapter(cdaa);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  new_dialog.show();
```

Here I have just inflated xml layout to alert dialog. Make sure you fetch each spinner with context to dialog. See above code for same.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Due to **memory leak**, happening so, When you are opening the one spinner it is able to get the valid context, but second time when you are trying to retrieve the another spinner it's actually getting `null` as a context and not populating anything. But When you are using  both the spinner in `Activity` out of `Alert-Dialog`, its' actually getting a `valid context` always. Thus for that time you are not getting any error and it populates correctly.

So, to avoid memory leak, use `getApplicationContext()` to retrieve the context for spinner  ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> carpetas = new ArrayAdapter<String>
       (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista_k);


ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador_textos = new ArrayAdapter<String>
      (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista_lista_textos);
```